# ejabberd : How to extract data from xml element

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erl

I have this packet :

```
{xmlelement,"presence", [{"xml:lang","en"}, {"ver","6.00.00"}, {"to", "test@conference.localhost/user"}],
                        [{xmlelement,"c", [{"xmlns", "http://jabber.org/protocol/caps"}, {"node", "http://www.google.com/xmpp/client/caps/"}, {"ver", "eVvrsq8jya/4AZMjFl5BeDKSmg4="}, {"hash","sha-1"}], []},
                        {xmlelement,"nick", [{"xmlns", "http://jabber.org/protocol/nick"}], [{xmlcdata,<<"user">>}]},
                        {xmlelement,"x", [{"xmlns", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"}], [{xmlelement,"history", [{"maxstanzas","20"}, {"maxchars","32768"}], []}]}]}
```

And I want to extract data from : ("maxchars" && "node")

What I'm doing is using functions located in xml.erl but i don't know how to do it .

Example for what I tried :

```
xml:get_subtag(Packet, "maxchars")
```

Comment: You seem to be using a very old version of ejabberd. New version uses #xmlel records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a recent version of ejabberd (= that is less than 3 years old), you can do as follow.

I assume packet is binary xmlel record:

```
P = {xmlel,<<"presence">>, [{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>}, {<<"ver">>,<<"6.00.00">>}, {<<"to">>, <<"test@conference.localhost/user">>}],
     [{xmlel,<<"c">>, [{<<"xmlns">>, <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/caps">>}, {<<"node">>, <<"http://www.google.com/xmpp/client/caps/">>}, {<<"ver">>, <<"eVvrsq8jya/4AZMjFl5BeDKSmg4=">>}, {<<"hash">>,<<"sha-1">>}], []},
      {xmlel,<<"nick">>, [{<<"xmlns">>, <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/nick">>}], [{xmlcdata,<<"user">>}]},
      {xmlel,<<"x">>, [{<<"xmlns">>, <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>}], [{xmlel,<<"history">>, [{<<"maxstanzas">>,<<"20">>}, {<<"maxchars">>,<<"32768">>}], []}]}]}.
```

You can then do:

```
X = fxml:get_subtag_with_xmlns(P, <<"x">>, <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>).                                                                                        
H = fxml:get_subtag(X, <<"history">>).
{value, MS} = fxml:get_tag_attr(<<"maxstanzas">>, H).
{value, MC} = fxml:get_tag_attr(<<"maxchars">>, H).
```

MS and MC contains your values:

```
MS = <<"20">>
MC = <<"32768">>
```

Comment: I'm using ejabberd 2.1.13 . Can I do it with the functions in xml.erl ?
cuz there isn't function named : get_subtag_with_xmlns in old version

Comment: I'm trying to add (get_subtag_with_xmlns) function to xml.erl what I'm doing here : http://paste.ubuntu.com/15558018/

is it true ?

Comment: just use get_subtag then and ignore namespace. Note: You should really not use a version release in june 2013. You are missing a lot of security fixes.

Comment: I'm using this version before 2 years and I added to it some helpful function in muc-room ... etc and I found it much GOOD i think all of ejabberd version are good :D . so I can't leave to a newer version.

Comment: Sorry but I'm newer in erlang. Also i think ejabberd going to make me learn this language little by little.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this, it's pretty basic but it's working fine, although I'm pretty sure is quite inefficient and/or there might be better ways for doing this (wait for the cavalry to arrive):

```
1> X = {xmlelement,"presence", [{"xml:lang","en"}, {"ver","6.00.00"}, {"to", "test@conference.localhost/user"}], [{xmlelement,"c", [{"xmlns", "http://jabber.org/protocol/caps"}, {"node", "http://www.google.com/xmpp/client/caps/"}, {"ver", "eVvrsq8jya/4AZMjFl5BeDKSmg4="}, {"hash","sha-1"}], []}, {xmlelement,"nick", [{"xmlns", "http://jabber.org/protocol/nick"}], [{xmlcdata,<<"user">>}]}, {xmlelement,"x", [{"xmlns", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"}], [{xmlelement,"history", [{"maxstanzas","20"}, {"maxchars","32768"}], []}]}]}.
{xmlelement,"presence",
            [{"xml:lang","en"},
             {"ver","6.00.00"},
             {"to","test@conference.localhost/user"}],
            [{xmlelement,"c",
                         [{"xmlns","http://jabber.org/protocol/caps"},
                          {"node","http://www.google.com/xmpp/client/caps/"},
                          {"ver","eVvrsq8jya/4AZMjFl5BeDKSmg4="},
                          {"hash","sha-1"}],
                         []},
             {xmlelement,"nick",
                         [{"xmlns","http://jabber.org/protocol/nick"}],
                         [{xmlcdata,<<"user">>}]},
             {xmlelement,"x",
                         [{"xmlns","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"}],
                         [{xmlelement,"history",
                                      [{"maxstanzas","20"},
                                       {"maxchars","32768"}],
                                      []}]}]}
2> {xmlelement,_,[{_,_},{_,_},{_,_}],[{xmlelement,_,[{_,_},{"node",Node},{_,_},{_,_}],[]},{xmlelement,_,[{_,_}],[{xmlcdata,_}]},{xmlelement,_,[{_,_}],[{xmlelement,_,[{_,_},{"maxchars",MaxChars}],[]}]}]} = X.
{xmlelement,"presence",
            [{"xml:lang","en"},
             {"ver","6.00.00"},
             {"to","test@conference.localhost/user"}],
            [{xmlelement,"c",
                         [{"xmlns","http://jabber.org/protocol/caps"},
                          {"node","http://www.google.com/xmpp/client/caps/"},
                          {"ver","eVvrsq8jya/4AZMjFl5BeDKSmg4="},
                          {"hash","sha-1"}],
                         []},
             {xmlelement,"nick",
                         [{"xmlns","http://jabber.org/protocol/nick"}],
                         [{xmlcdata,<<"user">>}]},
             {xmlelement,"x",
                         [{"xmlns","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"}],
                         [{xmlelement,"history",
                                      [{"maxstanzas","20"},
                                       {"maxchars","32768"}],
                                      []}]}]}
3> Node.
"http://www.google.com/xmpp/client/caps/"
4> MaxChars.
"32768"
5>
```

On line `2>` we pattern match the values that you are expecting in that "format". Place the *bindings* in the locations you want to get the values from and, if possible, establish some constraints like, for instance, the atoms that won't change in the XML packet. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: yes. I get it thank you but I think there is a function in xml.erl built to catch data like this. I think it's better than this.